# Why are my browserify require paths not resolving in windows?

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, browserify

I'm trying to get a very basic browserify example going, but I am getting an error in my node.js command prompt on Windows7 that is driving me nuts.  It looks like the browserify is just plain not resolving the / in my paths to windows \ paths.  Using \ in the paths works just fine.

The error:

```
C:\Projects\Gameplan\gameplan>browserify -e src/javascript/app2.js
Error: module "../appmodules/module1.js" not found from     "C:\\Projects\\Gameplan\\gameplan\\src\\javascript\\app2.js"
  at notFound (C:\nodejs\node_modules\browserify\index.js:811:15)
  at C:\nodejs\node_modules\browserify\index.js:761:23
  at C:\nodejs\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\browser-resolve\index.js:185:24
  at C:\nodejs\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:44:14
  at process (C:\nodejs\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:113:43)
  at C:\nodejs\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:122:21
  at load (C:\nodejs\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:54:43)
  at C:\nodejs\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:60:22
  at C:\nodejs\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:16:47
  at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

My app.js file:

```
'use strict';
var module1 = require("../appmodules/module1.js");

// This line works fine on windows!
//var module1 = require("..\\appmodules\\module1.js");
```

My module1.js file:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function() { console.log("test"); };
```

My folder structure is

```
/src/javascript/app2.js
/src/javascript/appmodules/module1.js
```

and I am running this command:

```
browserify -e /src/javascript/app2.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement `require("../appmodules/module1.js");` running from `/src/javascript/app2.js` will actually look in `/src/appmodules/module1.js`.

Go ahead and replace `..` with a single dot: `.`, to look in the right directory.

Comment: I actually had require('appmodules/module1.js'); at one point, but I think the internal resolution algorithm must require that relative paths start with ./

Comment: Yep! So doing `require('appmodules/module1.js')` will look for the module *named* "appmodules/module1.js" (either in `node_modules/` or a similar location). To specify the *location* of the module you'd like the require (instead of the name), you need to let require know for sure that you are specifying a path - by prepending the location with a `./` or something of that nature.

Comment: THAT finally makes sense.  Thanks!